# What does the deflect method of android.telecom.Call does?

Tags: android

I don't understand the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/Call.html#deflect(android.net.Uri)) of the deflect method, can you please explain it to me in better words and with example if you can.

```
/**
 * Instructs this {@link #STATE_RINGING} {@code Call} to deflect.
 *
 * @param address The address to which the call will be deflected.
 */
public void deflect(Uri address) {
    mInCallAdapter.deflectCall(mTelecomCallId, address);
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to get any progress with this? I'm also looking for more details about it but I can't find much information out it